# Finding velocity of a fast-moving charged particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, charge, velocity

How do we find the **velocity of a fast-moving charged particle** at the end of an electric field, considering that the mass of the particle will change according to the special theory of relativity.

Note that the velocity of the particle is produced **purely due to the force exerted by the electric field.**

Let the charged particle be accelerated through a potential difference of **4V** and the charged particle be an **alpha particle**.

Also, don't forget to consider that the **particle's mass will change** according to the special theory of relativity.

**Thanks**

Comment: Please remember that "do my work for me" questions aren't allowed here. You have to show some work that you tried and people will help you with the problems you have. Also, while it's possible to define a mass that changes with motion in special relativity, this notion has been abandoned for a very long time. So you should probably write your calculation without it, favoring the invariant mass.

Comment: "Also, don't forget to consider that the particle's mass will change according to the special theory of relativity." <-- The mass of particle (namely, its rest mass) does not change with speed.

Comment: @Miyase so at this platform we have to first detail out our struggle, the dead-ends, the re-tries, and the crying. Why can't someone just come straight to the question. We aren't supposed to write novels here. We are supposed to ask questions. And this was a genuine question I had; it wasn't copied from textbook exercise or something

Comment: You can use the fact that the particle is descending the potential $\Delta U = q\Delta V$ and this is gained as kinetic energy by the particle $(\gamma-1)m_0 c^2$ where $m_0$ is the rest mass (not changing with velocity) and $\gamma =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ from which you can find $v$.

Comment: @MuhammadFahadIqbalKhan Remember that people help you on their free time. No one is asking you to write a novel, just to show a little effort. Every day we have students who drop their exercise on us and expect us to do their work for them. Remember [what you agreed to](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) when you signed up on this site.

Comment: @Miyase I am sorry. I think I got a little carried away there. I will try to keep what you said in mind.

Comment: @MuhammadFahadIqbalKhan No problem. :) Have a good day.